# How to select userflow based on request's subdomain? (ASP.NET, Azure AD B2C, Microsoft.Identity.Web)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, multi-tenant

We have a website made using ASP.NET 6.0.408.
This is a multitenant app, meaning it has one database for multiple customers.
A customer is identified by the subdomain of the request.
If a user accesses the site by entering `customer1.myapp.com` in his search bar, then we want to present him (if he's not already authenticated) with an authentication flow (called user flow or custom policy in Azure Ad B2C) specific to customer1.
We succeeded doing that even if (as far as I can tell) there is no api to do that easily with Microsoft.Identity.Web.

Here's an extract of the code in `Program.cs`:

```
 builder.Services
            .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc;
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut += OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc;
            });
// ...

app.UseSession();
// Determine the subdomain, check if it corresponds to an existing customer, then put it in session.
app.UseSubdomainResolver();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// ...

 private static async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc(RedirectContext context)
    {
        string? subdomain = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("subdomain");
        if (subdomain == null)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            return;
        }

        
        context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.Replace("b2c_1_default", $"b2c_1_{subdomain}");

        await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

The workaround we found is to register an event handler OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc, in which we change the default userflow (defined in appsettings.json) mentionned in the IssuerAddress.

Fairly hacky but it works.
Now we want to call our API which serves as a portal to the database (we have multiple client apps), which is protected using Azure Ad B2C.
To call the protected API from our website, we need to call a second endpoint of Azure Ad B2C, after the user has been authentified, in order to obtain an access token which will be sent with all subsequent requests to the API.
By default, the endpoint is `https://myapp.b2clogin.com/tfp/solasauth.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_default/oauth2/v2.0/token`, and Microsoft.Identity.Web exposes an API to request the access token, take care of refreshing that token etc.:

```
builder.Services
            .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc;
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut += OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc;
            })
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { builder.Configuration["API:Scope"] })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Again, we search for a hacky way to change the token endpoint, but nothing found this time.

Here's the question:
Is there really no way to change that endpoint before the UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization middlewares are called?
And is there a better way to achieve the desired behavior using the technologies mentionned?
If the answer is negative, do you know of any library that makes this fairly easy to do?

Notes:

- Our website requires to be authenticated from the beginning, so there is no signin button to be clicked, with a controller action behind which takes care of launching the right userflow.
  Everything thus happens before the UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization middlewares.

## Edit: Using authorization code flow

I tried using authorization code flow, but the documentation using Microsoft.Identity.Web [keeps using the implicit or hybrid flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#enable-id-token-implicit-grant).
I stumbled upon some SO posts and Github issues related to that:

- [Azure AD B2C error AADB2C90057 when I am NOT trying to use the implicit flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554550/azure-ad-b2c-error-aadb2c90057-when-i-am-not-trying-to-use-the-implicit-flow)
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/109393
- [Azure B2C authentication with Implicit Grant Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723820/azure-b2c-authentication-with-implicit-grant-flow)

I ended up unchecking these boxes in the app registration settings:
[image]

and leaving the code intact.
Still, I get the exact same behavior (which is very strange, I would have expected an error saying me that implicit flow is not possible; are changes made in the azure portal taking time to take effect?).

Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe Microsoft.Identity.Web doesn't easily allow the authorization code flow, and instead default to implicit/hybrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Here's what worked: As advised by Dave D, I switched from implicit to (authorization) code flow by unchecking the two boxes mentionned in the post, and by enforcing `Microsoft.Identity.Web` the authorization code flow with (see the change of `options.ResponseType`):

```
builder.Services
            .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind(configSection, options);
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                // ...
            });
```

Then I removed these calls:

```
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { builder.Configuration["API:Scope"] })
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

With these, the request to the token endpoint happens **before** the delegate I attached to `options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` runs.
Thus the token endpoint called is the one determined using the user flow I put in my `appsettings.json` (which I called `B2C_1_Default`), not necessarily the one I want, which depends on the request's subdomain.

Without these calls, `Microsoft.Identity.Web` still calls the token endpoint (as evidenced by the fact that I successfully find an access token in a delegate to `OnTokenResponseReceivedFunc`, accessible via `context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken`), I just need to specify the scope in the options:

```
builder.Services
            .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind(configSection, options);
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.Scope.Add(builder.Configuration["API:Scope"]);
                // ...
            });
```

It seems to work. The access token is available in the delegate to `OnTokenResponseReceived`, which I put in a distributed cache:

```
    private static async Task OnTokenResponseReceivedFunc(TokenResponseReceivedContext context)
    {
        // Store the access token in the distributed cache
        var distributedCache = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();
        await distributedCache.SetStringAsync("access_token", context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);

        // Don't remove this line
        await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

I can the access the cache in my http client and controller actions.

Done!

PS:

- I removed the line `options.SaveTokens = true;`, which only makes sense if using implicit flow.
- I'll probably need to change the scope dynamically at some point. I suppose I'll find a property to change in the delegate to `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the OpenID Connect `code` flow then you can handle the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event to either change the token endpoint or to make additional calls to the token endpoint manually, or handle the `OnTokenValidated` event to make additional calls after you've received an initial token for your app.

For example:

```cs
opt.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived += ctx =>
{
    // where the name of the custom policy has been manually added to `Properties.Items` earlier in the request/response chain
    if (ctx.Properties?.Items.TryGetValue("customPolicy", out var customPolicy) == true)
    {
        ctx.TokenEndpointRequest.TokenEndpoint = $"{opt.Instance}/{opt.Domain}/{customPolicy}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

Comment: Logs tell me that the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived handler is called after the request to the token endpoint (which still corresponds to the default configs). I indeed already tried and was surprised to discover that.

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me logs show that event being raised before a token is acquired. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/775028fdd25256ee7d9e70402dc73744b5977550/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L697C72-L697C72) it also seems to be called before token acquisition.

Both of those are provided you're using `code` flow.

Comment: If you're not using `code` flow, if you're using `hybrid` or `implicit`, then token(s) will already have been returned via the front-channel and there's no back-channel call to the token endpoint. In which case I think the only event you can rely on is `OnTokenValidated`.

Comment: Oh ok, we are indeed using `implicit`. I will see if we can use `code` flow instead, and try again, or try to do something with `OnTokenValidated`. I'll keep you informed of the results.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using the `code` flow if you can as it's more secure - tokens are only exchanged server-to-server, they're not accessible via the browser, unlike the `implicit` and `hybrid` flows.

Comment: I agree. I just edited the post to document my attempt to use the authorization code flow, if you can look at it, and maybe share snippets of your code if you have something working. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254676/discussion-between-yann-and-dave-d).