# Azure AD B2C custom policy for simple signin using OpenID Connect fails on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are building a website using ASP.NET 6.0.408.
This is a multi-tenant app, meaning customers share the same database.
We distinguish the customer making the request by the subdomain.
For example if a user requests the website at `customer1.myapp.com`, we suppose he's an employee of customer1, and run the custom policy associated with customer1.
Indeed, each customer can choose it's authentication method (OpenID Connect or SAML with he's IDP, or use our Azure AD B2C tenant as IDP if he doesn't have one).
We made it work with user flows (check an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76762651/11760045) to know how).

Now we want to do the same with custom policies, because we need to:

- be able to use SAML
- be able to customize the UI
- be able to check if the value returned by the customer's IDP for a custom claim is a valid one

Otherwise, nothing crazy. We basically need two kinds of custom policy:

- one that duplicates the signin userflow, connecting to Azure AD B2C with OpenID Connect
- one for connecting to a customer's IDP using OpenID Connect
- (BONUS for now) one for connecting to a customer's IDP using SAML

The difficulty is that we want, for OpenID Connect, to use the `code` response type, because it's necessary for us to change the policy used dynamically, based on the request's subdomain (by the way, if you know a better way to choose a custom policy depending on the request's subdomain, or a way to branch inside a big custom policy, or else, we are very interested).

We succeeded making a simple signing policy using `id_token`. The version using `code` is basically a copy, but with the response type change and a `client_secret` cryptographic key added.

Now when we run it, everything go well until we submit the credentials in the signin form:
[image]

Pretty strange. In the app, we use `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` as a client to Azure AD B2C.

Finally, the question: What could be the source of the error, and a solution?

The suspect technical profile is:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="InternalSigninValidation">
    <DisplayName>Internal Signin validation</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenant}.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">{ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework client id}</Item>
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">{IdentityExperienceFramework client id}</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ClientSecret" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue={ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework client id} />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue={IdentityExperienceFramework client id} />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```